# Messenger sending multiple Post requests per user input

Tags: python-3.x, rest, flask, http-post, facebook-messenger-bot

I am using Facebook Messenger and its send API. I also use ngrok as the server to handle the traffic. My chatbot worked fine a few days ago but now after a bit of debugging it seems that Messenger, with every input from the user, sends multiple post request one after the other very quickly. I had a thought if it might be latency issues as my chatbot that responds does take a while to process. My chatbot takes a long time due to all the requests but after a while it does manage to answer all the requests with a 200 response. If so how do I make Messenger not send multiple Post requests and flood my ngrok webhook? If it's something else how do I deal with the issue?

This is the code that listens to the requests:

```
@app.route("/webhook", methods=['GET','POST'])
def listen():
    """This is the main function flask uses to
    listen at the `/webhook` endpoint"""
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return verify_webhook(request)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        payload = request.get_json()
        print(payload)
        event = payload['entry'][0]['messaging']
        for x in event:
            if is_user_message(x):
                text = x['message']['text']
                sender_id = x['sender']['id']
                respond(sender_id, text)

        return "ok", 200
```

Comment: One possible solution which has nothing to do with Messenger is to use multiprocessing to respond to messages, while sending a 200 back right away

Comment: Id rather not go through that. Will that not increase response time? Is there a sort of timeout for the Messenger Graph API that makes it resend a request? Would there be a way to increase that timeout time?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about webhooks [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook#change_webhook). It does not look like you can change the timeout period.

> #### Webhook Performance Requirements
>
> Your webhook should meet the following minimum performance standards:
>
> - Respond to all webhook events with a 200 OK.
> - Respond to all webhook events in 20 seconds or less.

If you would want to implement a multiprocessing solution it may look like this:

```
from threading import Thread as Sub

@app.route("/webhook", methods=['GET','POST'])
def listen():
    """This is the main function flask uses to
    listen at the `/webhook` endpoint"""
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return verify_webhook(request)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        payload = request.get_json()
        print(payload)
        event = payload['entry'][0]['messaging']
        for x in event:
            if is_user_message(x):
                text = x['message']['text']
                sender_id = x['sender']['id']
                sub = Sub(target=respond, args=[sender_id, text])
                sub.start()

        return "ok", 200
```

If this gives you issues with shared scope or with flask itself, consider using `multiprocessing` instead. For this simply switch to

```
from multiprocessing import Process as Sub
```